# How to control the anchor position with the fixed nav bar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When I click on the anchors i.e (Due South Australia, SA Dining Guide, SA Style, SA Accommodation Guide, Backpackers Short Breaks Australia ) on this [page](https://hwrmedia.com.au/hwr-publications/) then the section moves up a little bit because of the sticky header.

Answer (score 0):

you should adjust this value `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top`. like `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top+50;` or `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top-50;`in custom.js.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Add smooth scrolling to all links
      $(".hashtag a").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();

          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;

          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top-100

            // scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top+50;
          }, 1000, function(){

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        } // End if
      });
    });
```

Comment: If I added this "scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top+50; " to my code then it is not scrolled smoothly into that position as it was before.

Comment: remove the `;` semicolon here `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top+50;`. it should be `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top+50`

Comment: set `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top-100;`

Comment: I have set top-100 but problem is still there :(

Comment: Here is the URL of my website (https://hwrmedia.com.au/).When I scroll down to the HWR Publications section and click on any post of that section, It goes to particular post on another page, hiding the content under the sticky navbar. For this I have used this js code:

  $(document).ready(function(){
      if (window.location.hash == "#moreInfo") {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#moreInfo").offset().top-100
         }, 1000);
      }
   });

Comment: Custom publication?

Comment: you wrote code for click event `$(".hashtag a").on('click', function(event) {`. you have to write code on page load.

Answer (score 0):

add this java script in footer for add top offset.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $(".hashtag a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

         // Store hash
         var hash = this.hash;


        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area

        var target_offset = $(hash).offset() ? $(hash).offset().top : 0;
        //change this number to create the additional off set        
        var customoffset = 40
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset - customoffset}, 1000, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```